# Image magick - Merge a picture over all pictures in the folder (watermark)

Tags: imagemagick

1. I have a picture in PNG format, watermark.png (300x300 pixel) (transparency)
2. I have many pictures in JPG format, in a folder 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc
   (300x300 pixel)

How to merge them,

```
watermark.png above the 1.jpg
watermark.png above the 2.jpg
watermark.png above the picture in folder
```

how can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when you want to apply the same process to lots of images, you use **ImageMagick** `mogrify` command, but that is a bit difficult because you need a way to separate all the background images from the name of the watermark image that you want to use with a `-composite` command.

One neat trick, is to use the `-draw` command like this:

```
magick mogrify -draw "image SrcOver 0,0 0,0 watermark.png" *.jpg
```

If you want to test it before potentially wrecking all your images by overwriting in the wrong place, one way is to add `-format GIF` and all the output files will be GIF files and won't overwrite the input files.

Another option is to run:

```
mkdir result
magick mogrify -path result ... as above ...
```

and the output images will appear in the `result` directory without overwriting the originals.

[image]

Comment: 1. I've tried the first method but "unable to open the image", I read this link, http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/ but still the same >>> magick mogrify -draw "image SrcOver 0,0 0,0 'watermark.png'" *.jpg

Comment: Please click `edit` under your original question and add in the EXACT command you ran and the EXACT error message. Thank you.

Comment: I've just typed the problems under my question

Comment: Oh, you are on Windows which is being stupid. Are your filenames ending in `.JPG` or `.JPEG` or `.jpeg`? You will need to use whatever matches your filenames.

Comment: On the second method, you don't type `as above`, but you type the other parts of the command above in my answer. I was just shortening it to show you just the different parts with the rest remaining unchanged, i.e. *"as above"*.

Comment: hahaha, sorry my fault, first method, I think *. jpg is about to convert all the files into .jpg, but I just realized it was a command to read all jpg in the folder

Comment: it works 1000%! thank you and sorry, I am a newbie about this image magick :)

Comment: No problems, we're all here to learn :-) Good luck with your project!